# Logic change from negatives to affirmative

Tags: sql, sql-server, logic

The following works but a colleague is struggling with the logic:

```
WHERE 
    FirstDate <> '01 JAN 2015'
    OR
    Name NOT IN ('Foo', 'Bar')
```

Is it easy to switch from the above to a script that uses `=` instead of `<>` and `IN` rather than `NOT IN`?

Any changes should not impact the data returned: we simply would like to make the code more readable.

Comment: do you still want the same rows ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk yes - same rows required: just would like a `WHERE clause` that is easy to understand when we come back to it in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use De Morgan's Law:

```
WHERE NOT (
    FirstDate = '01 JAN 2015'
    AND
    Name IN ('Foo', 'Bar') )
```

You still have to use a `NOT`operator though.

Via Wikipedia:

> [image]

Comment: @whytheq No, not at all. It is a valuable addition to my answer.